# Logging in from /review redirects to /community (and a 404)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, login, redirection

I just tried to log in from review (after recovering from a battery-loss incident) using one of the review log-in links.

> [image: login]

I was able to log in but was re-directed to the 404 because /review has been replaced with /community.

> [image: community 404]

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Log out/open an "incognito" window.
2. Navigate to stackoverflow.com/review
3. Log in.

I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 7, if it's relevant and was logging in using my Google account.

P.S. Is /community something? Was it ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, that path is some ancient pre-release route for the new(-ish) review queues.  Looks like it just never got updated in that code path.

The next build will fix it.